# how to fetch data without button click

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio-2.2, android-developer-api

**how to fetch first image without click fetch image button**

[click to view image](https://i1.wp.com/www.simplifiedcoding.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/android-programming-tutorial-layout.png?w=289&ssl=1)

this code work fine but on click fetch image button but i want fetch image with out click fetch images button i want to remove this button

```
Public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {

    private String imagesJSON;

    private static final String JSON_ARRAY ="result";

    private static final String IMAGE_URL = "url";

    private JSONArray arrayImages= null;

    private int TRACK = 0;

    private static final String IMAGES_URL = "http://www.simplifiedcoding.16mb.com/ImageUpload/getAllImages.php";

    private Button buttonFetchImages;
    private Button buttonMoveNext;
    private Button buttonMovePrevious;
    private ImageView imageView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        buttonFetchImages = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFetchImages);
        buttonMoveNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
        buttonMovePrevious = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPrev);
        buttonFetchImages.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonMoveNext.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonMovePrevious.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    private void extractJSON(){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(imagesJSON);
            arrayImages = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void showImage(){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = arrayImages.getJSONObject(TRACK);
            getImage(jsonObject.getString(IMAGE_URL));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void moveNext(){
        if(TRACK < arrayImages.length()){
            TRACK++;
            showImage();
        }
    }

    private void movePrevious(){
        if(TRACK>0){
            TRACK--;
            showImage();
        }
    }



    private void getAllImages() {
        class GetAllImages extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
            ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Fetching Data...","Please Wait...",true,true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                imagesJSON = s;
                extractJSON();
                showImage();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String uri = params[0];
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(uri);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                    String json;
                    while((json = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                        sb.append(json+"\n");
                    }

                    return sb.toString().trim();

                }catch(Exception e){
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        GetAllImages gai = new GetAllImages();
        gai.execute(IMAGES_URL);
    }

    private void getImage(String urlToImage){
        class GetImage extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap>{
            ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                URL url = null;
                Bitmap image = null;

                String urlToImage = params[0];
                try {
                    url = new URL(urlToImage);
                    image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return image;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Downloading Image...","Please wait...",true,true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
                loading.dismiss();
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
        GetImage gi = new GetImage();
        gi.execute(urlToImage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == buttonFetchImages) {
            getAllImages();
        }
        if(v == buttonMoveNext){
            moveNext();
        }
        if(v== buttonMovePrevious){
            movePrevious();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: call getAllImages() inside onCreate() method.

Comment: can you correct my code and paste it pls.

Comment: too much of tags.  What you need to do is check what happens when you click on that button ,, do that stuff inside the onCreate method

Comment: I done this before but i face error

Comment: cannot be ,then paste the error log so we can help , may be you call that method before you initialize the view   buttonFetchImages = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFetchImages); so call that method after the initialization

Comment: @SyedMuzzammilMian update ur question with error log. Be specific with what ur need.

Comment: how to pase this     public void getAllImages() {
            class GetAllImages extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
                ProgressDialog loading;
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Fetching Data...","Please Wait...",true,true);
                }    inside oncreate method

Comment: all i want is when i run a programm first image display from json without click top button then other images show on next previous button

Comment: @SyedMuzzammilMian keep GetAllImages asynctask out of getAllImages() method. create instance of GetAllImages inside onCreate and execue it.

Comment: keep verything as it is ,only paste getAllImages() ; <-this inside onCreate and it will call that method outside of the onCreate, you dont need to add all

Comment: bro i'm a newbie id'nt know much can u create instance for me ...pls

Comment: @Syed Muzzammil Mian update your edits suggested

Comment: when i paste getAllImages(); inside onCreate image not display

Comment: @Nas  thanks bro ....    paste getAllImages(); inside oncreate is working....

Comment: I have problem in this pls check on this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41074877/how-to-fetch-json-data-on-scoll-to-bottom-in-fragment-listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger it in onCreate(),but you must not run it on UI thread,for it might be a time-consuming operation.Read [Specifying the Code to Run on a Thread](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/define-runnable.html) to help,
you might add the following block in your onCreate() method:

```
new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getAllImages();
        }
    }.run();
```

Comment: sorry to see that you have already use AsyncTask in getAllImages(),just add getAllyImages();  to the last line of onCreate() method.

Comment: is it  ok with the fetch button clicked? any warning log?

Comment: I have face 1 more problem can u help me with this ?

Comment: pls check this link help me out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41074877/how-to-fetch-json-data-on-scoll-to-bottom-in-fragment-listview